# Cant make Prediction on OLS Model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm Building an OLS Model but cant make any predictions.

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Building the model :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Madrid','New York','Madrid','London','Tokyo','London','Tokyo'], 
     'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Bitcoin','Master Card','Bitcoin','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Bitcoin'],
     'Colateral':['Yes','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes'],
     'Client Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
     'Total':[100,100,200,300,10,20,40,50,60,100,500]}

d = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index('Client Number')

df = pd.get_dummies(d,prefix='', prefix_sep='')

X = df[['Lisbon','London','Madrid','New York','Tokyo','Bitcoin','Master Card','Visa','No','Yes']]
Y = df['Total']

X1 = sm.add_constant(X)
reg = sm.OLS(Y, X1).fit()

reg.summary()
```

Prediction:

```
d1 = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon'], 
     'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Visa'],
     'Colateral':['Yes','Yes','No'],
     'Client Number':[11,12,13],
     'Total':[0,0,0]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1).set_index('Client Number')

df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1,prefix='', prefix_sep='')
y_new = df1[['Lisbon','Tokyo','Visa','No','Yes']]
x_new = df1['Total']
mod = sm.OLS(y_new, x_new)

mod.predict(reg.params)
```

Then it shows : ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (11,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 11 (dim 0)

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed prediction part of code with my comments:

```
d1 = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon'], 
     'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Visa'],
     'Colateral':['Yes','Yes','No'],
     'Client Number':[11,12,13],
     'Total':[0,0,0]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1).set_index('Client Number')
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1,prefix='', prefix_sep='')
x_new = df1.drop(columns='Total')
```

The main problem is different number of dummies in training `X1` and `x_new` dataset.
Below I add missing dummy columns and fill it with zero:

```
x_new = x_new.reindex(columns = X1.columns, fill_value=0)
```

now `x_new` has proper number of columns equal to training dataset `X1`:

```
               const  Lisbon  London  Madrid  ...  Master Card  Visa  No  Yes
Client Number                                 ...                            
11                 0       0       0       0  ...            0     1   0    1
12                 0       0       0       0  ...            0     1   0    1
13                 0       1       0       0  ...            0     1   1    0

[3 rows x 11 columns]
```

Finally predict on new dataset `x_new` using previously trained model `reg`:

```
reg.predict(x_new)
```

result:

```
Client Number
11     35.956284
12     35.956284
13    135.956284
dtype: float64
```

**APPENDIX**

As requested I enclose below fully reproducible code to test both training and prediction tasks:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Madrid','New York','Madrid','London','Tokyo','London','Tokyo'], 
     'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Bitcoin','Master Card','Bitcoin','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Bitcoin'],
     'Colateral':['Yes','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes'],
     'Client Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
     'Total':[100,100,200,300,10,20,40,50,60,100,500]}

d = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index('Client Number')

df = pd.get_dummies(d,prefix='', prefix_sep='')

X = df[['Lisbon','London','Madrid','New York','Tokyo','Bitcoin','Master Card','Visa','No','Yes']]
Y = df['Total']

X1 = sm.add_constant(X)
reg = sm.OLS(Y, X1).fit()

reg.summary()

###
d1 = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon'], 
     'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Visa'],
     'Colateral':['Yes','Yes','No'],
     'Client Number':[11,12,13],
     'Total':[0,0,0]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1).set_index('Client Number')
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1,prefix='', prefix_sep='')
x_new = df1.drop(columns='Total')

x_new = x_new.reindex(columns = X1.columns, fill_value=0)

reg.predict(x_new)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When i use the real data it shows ''cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'' ... any idea what problem it might have??

Comment: i then used a part of the data set to test out the training

Comment: Are You using the same dataset `df` as in question or another external data? If the same data I can provide reproducible working example with predicting part also.

Comment: same data set. Basically take a part of df, i tried to run the model

Comment: I enclosed full code to test in appendix to my answer. Please let me know If there are any errors and at what line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is that you are not using the same dummy transformation. That is, some values in df1 are absent. You can add the missing values/columns with the following code (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335718/keep-same-dummy-variable-in-training-and-testing-data)):

```
d1 = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon'], 
 'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Visa'],
 'Colateral':['Yes','Yes','No'],
 'Client Number':[11,12,13],
 'Total':[0,0,0]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1).set_index('Client Number')
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1,prefix='', prefix_sep='')
print(df1.shape)  # Shape is 3x6 but it has to be 3x11
# Get missing columns in the training test
missing_cols = set( df.columns ) - set( df1.columns )
# Add a missing column in test set with default value equal to 0
for c in missing_cols:
    df1[c] = 0
# Ensure the order of column in the test set is in the same order than in train set
df1 = df1[df.columns]
print(df1.shape)  # Shape is 3x11
```

Further, you mixed up `x_new` and `y_new`. So it should be:

```
x_new = df1.drop(['Total'], axis=1).values
y_new = df1['Total'].values
mod = sm.OLS(y_new, x_new)

mod.predict(reg.params)
```

Note that I used `x_new = df1.drop(['Total'], axis=1).values` instead of `df1[['Lisbon','Tokyo','Visa','No','Yes']]` as it is more convenient (in terms of 1) less prone to (typing)errors and 2) less code

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to either string-index all the words, or one-hot encode the values. ML models don't accept words, only numbers. Next, you want you X and y to be:

```
X = d.iloc[:,:-1]
y = d.iloc[:,-1]
```

This way X has a shape of [11,3] and y has a shape of [11,], which is the proper shapes needed.